# Power sum of two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

Let    $a + b i$   be a complex number whose absolute value is greater than  $1$   and whose argument is not a rational multiple of $\pi$ .

For  $n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$ define    $f(n) =| (a + b i )^n  +  (a - b i )^n  |$ 
where $|\cdot|$ denotes the absolute value.

It is easy to show that  $\limsup f(n) = \infty$ .

Is it also true that  $\liminf f(n) = \infty$ ?

Comment: 'It is easy to show that lim supf(n)=∞" OK, how?

Comment: It seems to me that the [equidistribution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem) will probably be useful here

Answer (score 0):

Thought this might be useful, but it's too long for a comment:

Denote $z = a + bi = re^{i \theta}$.  We note that
$$
f(n) = |z^n + (\overline z)^{n}| = r^n \left|e^{i n \theta} - e^{-in\theta} \right| = 2 r^n \sin (n\theta)
$$
So, proving that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f(n)\leq K$ amounts to showing that we can find arbitrarily large $n$ such that
$$
-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac K2 r^{-n}\right)
\leq[n \theta]
\leq
\sin^{-1} \left(\frac K2 r^{-n}\right)
$$
Where $[n \theta]$ is the the value of $n \theta - 2 \pi k$ for $k \in \mathbb Z$ that falls between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.  Note that $\sin^{-1} x \approx x$ for sufficiently small $x$.

This does not seem like it can be directly deduced from equidistribution.